# Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE - chrome upgrade to 72

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

After chrome update to 72, I started to receive

> Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

For my app I wrote own implementation on back, and it was working fine until chrome upgraded to 72 (and still works if I downgrade).

Request from front is the same, but response stopped to work, am I missing some new (required) field?
Did something changed in specification (implementation) of wbesocket protocol?

All lines are separated with `\r\n` and at the end of the response is double it.

What is the problem I don't know, can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Here is request/response examples:

***Request:***

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:43594
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:8181
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 8+Ck6qJuBfyiRyN0civK1Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: ypsilon
```

***Response:***

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: RmyrkdBT/F21bXWmdVFzwHxCvq4=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: ypsilon
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, that behavior was dye to empty charackter before the last two sections, and now it seems that chrome versions before 72 just trancated them and newer is not

Comment: Can you add an example of what changed in the server's response to make it work?